# Using Connected app for SOAP based Integration salesforce

Tags: apex, community, integration

Generally, we use username-password based authentication mechanism if we want external application to consume our Salesforce `SOAP webservice`. And for calling SF `REST webservice` we need to create connected app so that we get the client id and secret key for authenticating with Salesforce.

But can we do the other way round, meaning, just wondering, Is it possible for the external systems to call Salesforce SOAP webservice using Connected app (client id and secret key) for authentication?

Or is it like we can't use Connected app in case of SOAP based webservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use the OAuth flow (via Connected App), you can use the Access Token you received with any API (as long as you have the correct [scope](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5)). It's as a simple as using the Access Token in the `sessionId` [SessionHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_sessionheader.htm) property.

Comment: Okay, so which means In case of SOAP webservice as well, I can use Client ID and secret key (received in Connected app) for authentication and the access token that I will receive , I can copy it in session Id tag? Is that correct? Is yes, then what could be the difference between session Id and access token even though they both can authenticate?

Comment: @sfdc07 AT can be limited by "scope" of the Connected App, and the manner of acquisition are different (OAuth flow versus SOAP login call). Technical differences aside, AT and SID serve the same purpose; to allow access to Salesforce resources. However, AT is called AT because that term comes from the OAuth specification, while SID comes from the normal nomenclature used by many SOAP-based logins.

Comment: Perfect, that make sense. Thank you!